# Independence of consecutive rv in a sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, independence

I am studying the different types of convergences and found [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_2_sequence_of_random_variables.php) a first example about sequences of rv.
I have a question about the example presented in the website, that goes as follows:

> Consider the following random experiment: A fair coin is tossed once.
> Here, the sample space has only two elements $S=\{H,T\}$. We define a
> sequence of random variables $X1, X2, X3, ⋯$ on this sample space as
> follows:

\begin{equation}
X_n(s) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}\frac{1}{n+1} & \text{if }S=H \\1  & \text{if }S=T \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

**Are the $X_i$ independent?**
The proposed answer says that

> "No, since they are determined by the same coin toss. In particular,
> for $X_1$ and $X_2$ we can write"

\begin{equation}
P(X_1=1,X_2=1) = P(T) = 1/2 \hspace{1cm}(1)
\end{equation}
That is different from
\begin{equation}
P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)=1/4 \hspace{1cm}(2)
\end{equation}

I do not understand the logic behind (1), how to arrive to that 1/2 conclusion.

Thanks a lot in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand the logic behind (1), how to arrive to that 1/2 conclusion.

The sequence is given by a SINGLE coin toss. Thus the probability to have

$$\{1,1,1,1,1,\dots\}$$

is $0.5=P(T)$ which is also the probability to have $X_1=1$ or $X_2=1$ and thus the $X_i$ cannot be independent

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I still don't get it right. 
Every $X_n$ is a new rv in the sequence. For $n \in {1,2...N}$ the rv $X_n$ takes one of two values, each with probability 1/2, according to the result of one single coin toss, but each coin toss is different, we have N coin tosses, coming from N experiments.
I get that $P(T) = 1/2$ is constant for every $n$, but can't see why $P({1,1})=1/2$ or in your example, $P(\{1,1,1,1...\}) =1/2$ or how that affects other possible outcomes such as $\{0,0...\}$ or $\{1,0,1,0...\}$,  could you please elaborate a little more?
Thanks!

Comment: @nico_so :I try:

The sequence $X_n(s)$ is derived by only ONE coin toss. Suppose you get Tail....your sequence is

$$\{X_1;X_2\}=\{1;1\}$$

the conditional probability $P(X_2=1|X_1=1)=1$

This show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent. I do not think I can be more clear...but probabily the issue is that I am not able to explain you the the problem

Comment: From your answer I think that the problem is that I have a wrong understanding of what a sequence of rv actually is. For you say that the sequence $X_n$ is derived after one coin toss, meaning that that only one experiment will determine the whole sequence. So, I toss ONE COIN, only ONCE, if it lands tail I get the sequence $\{1,1,1,1,1...1\}$ but if it lands heads then $\{1/(1+1), 1/(1+2), 1/(1+3)...1/(1+n)\}$. That would be the correct interpretation then?

Comment: @nico_so : yes this is what I realized reading your link